# Ocean with mirror cube

Tags: cycles-render-engine, ocean-simulation

Im trying to recreate the attached effect. I have the ocean and a reflective cube down (as you can see on the attached image). But im struggling with the material of the cube and making the ocean a bit more wavy and dramatic looking.

I can fix most of the in photoshop, but I would love to learn how to fix some of these things in blender.

[image] [image]

Comment: Can you show your current render?

Comment: Just shared it :)

Comment: you should decrease your glossiness, also you need to put a bit of noise to make the surface a bit dirty, and also the angles are darker, I don't know how you could do it procedurally though...

Comment: Im using a Glossy BSDF with a roughness of 0.001

Comment: yes but the original doesn't seem so glossy

Comment: actually maybe the surface is not dirty, it might be droplets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it in Eevee and it was fun :).
I used [this free HDRI](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=sunset_in_the_chalk_quarry) to light the scene.

**Cube**

- *Metalness to 1* for highest reflectivity (just like real mirrors)
- *Musgrave and Noise* texture for those tiny black dots
- *Layer Weight > Facing* to control lighter/darker side.
- Dark edges. Add a *Bevel modifier* and set *Material: 1*

  - Then add a second material slot to your object with some dark material

**Ocean**

- *Wave Modifier* on a subdivided plane for large waves
- *Voronoi texture* as a Bump map for those tiny ripples

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[The HDRI](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=sunset_in_the_chalk_quarry) isn't packed, just download and put it next to the Blendfile :).

Comment: This helped a lot, 
Im not quite sure of the last step that you did? 

Then I also wanted to ask you if you would be willing to share the node tree for the ocean and how you managed to only have the HDR background with only the sky? (Sorry im have only been using blender for 30 days, but I love all the challenges that im faced with every day).

Comment: Hello :). No problem, I added the .blend and an  explanation for those dark edges. Enjoy, and welcome to Blender :).

Comment: You are the best! Thank you :)